# MPMoviePlayerController video not playing

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I used MPMoviePlayerController in my application.
 I got the right URL but MPMoviePlayer does not play video it shows only black screen.
 My code is as below:

```
[video setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"video_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 NSString *filename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4",[appdel.TempVideoUrl valueForKey:tag]];
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
 NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] ;
 theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
 theMovie.view.frame = CGRectMake(106, 18, 216, 235);
 [uploadview addSubview:theMovie.view];

  // Play the movie.
 [theMovie pause];
```

I got the URL like this:
    file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/6E1D4CB7-A08D-438B-9FE7-E2FD9B7B5EEC/Documents/136_1355227629.mp4

Comment: add [uploadview prepareToPlay]; before playing it

Comment: upload view is my subview in which i add movie player. Your suggested method shows mw error.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion when i used [theMovie prepareToPlay] is really works

Comment: can I add it as answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `[theMovie prepareToPlay];` before calling `[theMovie play];`.

> **prepareToPlay**
>
> Prepares a movie player for playback. (required)
>
> `- (void)prepareToPlay`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> If a movie player is not already prepared to play when you call the
>   play method, that method automatically calls this method. However, to
>   minimize playback delay, call this method before you call play.
>
> Calling this method may interrupt the movie player’s audio session.
>   For information on interruptions and how to resond to them, see Audio
>   Session Programming Guide. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
> ```
>
> Declared In MPMediaPlayback.h

Also you can use `isPreparedToPlay` for **checking whether a movie player is ready to play.**

Please refer this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for more.